# deserializing a nested array JSON in C# returning null values

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am getting null values returned when I deserialize a JSON using newtonSoft JSON. 
Here is my JSON:

```
        {"odata.metadata":"https://graph.abc.com/testapi",
    "value":
    [{"capabilityStatus":"Enabled",
    "consumedUnits":2,
    "objectId":"c9992e5ef110_6fd2c87-1e91e994b900",
    "prepaidUnits":{"enabled":25,"suspended":0,"warning":0},
    "servicePlans":
    [{"servicePlanId":"4ccb","servicePlanName":"YAMMER_ENTERPRISE"},
    {"servicePlanId":"bea4","servicePlanName":"RMS_S_ENTERPRISE"},
    {"servicePlanId":"43de","servicePlanName":"OFFICESUBSCRIPTION"},
    {"servicePlanId":"0fea","servicePlanName":"MCOSTANDARD"},
    {"servicePlanId":"e95be","servicePlanName":"SHAREPOINTWAC"},
    {"servicePlanId":"5dbe","servicePlanName":"SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE"},
    {"servicePlanId":"efb8","servicePlanName":"EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE"}],
    "skuId":"42f0-b197",
    "skuPartNumber":"ENTERPRISEPACK"}]}
```

and here are my classes:

```
    public class PrepaidUnits
            {
            public int enabled { get; set; }
            public int suspended { get; set; }
            public int warning { get; set; }
            }

            public class ServicePlan
            {
            public string servicePlanId { get; set; }
            public string servicePlanName { get; set; }
            }

            public class Value
            {
            public string capabilityStatus { get; set; }
            public int consumedUnits { get; set; }
            public string objectId { get; set; }
            public PrepaidUnits prepaidUnits { get; set; }
            public List<ServicePlan> servicePlans { get; set; }
            public string skuId { get; set; }
            public string skuPartNumber { get; set; }
            }

            public class Graphdata
            {
            public string odata_metadata { get; set; }
            public List<Value> value { get; set; }
            }
```

So here is the problem, when I deserialize using the following statement, I get returned null values for  servicePlanId and servicePlanName. what am I doing wrong here?

```
        var graphAPIDataDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServicePlan>(graphResult);
```

However, when I use the Graphdata class I can see all the values in the JSON response:

```
       var graphAPIDataDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Graphdata>(graphResult);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of any JSON parser. The string you give it is supposed to represent the object that you want to get out of it, so when you say:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServicePlan>(graphResult)
```

... you're instructing it to deserialize the *graph result* into a `ServicePlan` object. It creates a `ServicePlan`, looks at the object you've given it (the "graph result"), finds no properties named `servicePlanId`, etc., so it doesn't set any values on those properties.

If you're trying to create a `ServicePlan`, you need to pass it a string value more like `{"servicePlanId":"4ccb","servicePlanName":"YAMMER_ENTERPRISE"}`.

On the other hand, if you're trying to get the ServicePlans out of your deserialized graph result, you can say:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Graphdata>(text).value[0].servicePlans
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to get the ServicePlans out of the deserilized graph result. I was able to get it using your hint and using the following statement:  var graphAPIDataDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Graphdata>(graphResult).value[0].servicePlans;